# how to deploy django app on AWS windows server instance

Tags: django, windows, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy django app on aws having windows instance, gone through many doc and video but all are showing with ubuntu and linux machine. please provide any suggestion or right approach for doing this

Comment: refer this link https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-deploy-django-project-on-aws-ec2-server-23eb30d1533d

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, i had gone through that previously, these guy has not covered deployment process

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.